# Insert multiple rows using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert two rows to MySQL table using PHP PDO. Below is my code

```
$bundleParams[] = array(
     ':bundle_contract_id' => $contract_id,
     ':bundle_clin' => $clin,
     ':constituent_clin' => $constituent_clin,
     ':constituent_quantity' => $constituent_quantity,
     ':constituent_price' => $constituent_price,
     ':base_clin' => 'Y'
);
$bundleParams[] = array(
     ':bundle_contract_id' => $contract_id,
     ':bundle_clin' => $clin,
     ':constituent_clin' => 'DELL-COMPONENTS',
     ':constituent_quantity' => $constituent_quantity,
     ':constituent_price' => 0.00,
     ':base_clin' => 'N'
);
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO product_bundle(bundle_contract_id, bundle_clin, constituent_clin, constituent_quantity, constituent_price, base_clin) VALUES (:bundle_contract_id, :bundle_clin, :constituent_clin, :constituent_quantity, :constituent_price, :base_clin)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertSQL);
$stmt->execute($bundleParams);
```

When I execute the code I get the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

with message

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

What's wrong with this code?. Can anyone help me track the issue? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your $bundleParams is an array inside an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt->execute($array);` wants an associative array with the PDO bindings, you give a array of such arrays -> you have to do it for each of those so (as Your Common Sense already said) :

```
foreach ($bundleParams as $row)
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertSQL);
foreach ($bundleParams as $row)
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

All necessary explanations can be found in the linked answer.

Comment: I know its blatantly obvious to you and I but a bit of an explanation to the OP would be useful.

Comment: I tried, see answer below @RiggsFolly.